# How to code coverage for aggregate for loop?

Tags: unit-test

```
        public class WCT_CountryrealignUpdate2{
        @InvocableMethod
        public static void NewcountyUpdate2(List<id> countyIds1){
        Boolean t;
            List<New_country__c> newval = new List<New_country__c>();
            for (AggregateResult ar : [select count(Id) totalCount, Company_Realign__c countyId From Contact where Company_Realign__c = :countyIds1 GROUP BY Company_Realign__c ] ){
                Decimal getCount = (Decimal) ar.get('totalCount');
                  t=getCount>0?true:false;
                newval.add(new New_country__c(
                    Id = (Id) ar.get('countyId'), 
                    Alumni_contact_count__c = (Decimal) ar.get('totalCount'),Alumni_Present__c = t
                ));
                    System.debug('22222222222222'+ar);

            }
            update newval;
        }
        }
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class WCT_CountryrealignUpdateTest
{
public static  testmethod void count()
{
   List<New_country__c> CountryList = New List<New_country__c>();

   New_country__c company = new New_country__c(Name='Test098765', Domestic_Ultimate_DUNS_Number__c='012345678',Alumni_Present__c = True,Alumni_contact_count__c = 5,Parent__c = False,Status__c = 'Approved');
    insert company;

     New_country__c company1 = new New_country__c(Name='Test098765', Domestic_Ultimate_DUNS_Number__c='012345678',Alumni_Present__c = True,Alumni_contact_count__c = 5,Parent__c = False,Status__c = 'Approved');
    insert company1;

     User u = WCT_UtilTestDataCreation.createUser('test77642@cvm.com','System Administrator','CTS Out of Scope - Vendor Relationship Management','CVMLast','CVMFirst','cvmcvm',);  
    insert u;

    recordtype rt=[select id from recordtype where Name = 'Employee'];
    Contact cnt1 =WCT_UtilTestDataCreation.createEmployee(rt.id);
    cnt1.Company_Realign__c = company.id;
    insert cnt1;
    cnt1.Company_Realign__c = company1.id;
    update cnt1;
     List<id> Cid = New List<id>();
      Cid.add(cnt1.id);


    Test.startTest();

   WCT_CountryrealignUpdate.NewcountyUpdate(Cid);

    Test.stopTest();

  }    
}
```

[image]

Not able cover the higlited lines of code. Can any one please help to how cover for that piece of code.

Answer (score 6):

You are passing the wrong parameter to your method `NewcountyUpdate()`. It is coded to accept a set of `Id` values for `New_country__c` objects, and you are passing it a set containing the `Id` of one `Contact`. As a result, your aggregate query is guaranteed to return no results, as it's querying based on the supplied Ids corresponding to `New_country__c` records.

Your `Set` should contain the `Id`s of `company` and `company1` for your test to execute as designed.

Additionally, your unit test should be querying the updated data in your `New_country__c` records after executing `NewcountyUpdate()` and making assertions about the results. If you do not do so, your unit test becomes a "smoke test", which proves nothing except that the code does not crash under a specific set of circumstances.